# If $f$ is $L_1$ integrable, then $f$ times $\log(x)$ is integrable.

Tags: integration

Suppose $f(x_1,x_2):B_R(0) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f(0)=\infty$ and $f$ is in $L_1(B_R(0))$ ,then is it true that $$\int_{B_R(0)} f(x)\log(|x|)dx$$ is integrable  ?

Comment: your function is not integrable in the ball $B_R(0)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $R<1$, consider the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|^2\log^2(|x|)}$

Answer (score 0):

Think about the 1D case: on $[2,\infty)$, the function $\frac{1}{x \ln(x)^2}$ is integrable but $\frac{1}{x \ln(x)}$ is not. Transporting to $[0,1/2]$ by changing variables to $u=1/x$ gives an example on a bounded domain, as in your original problem.

For radial functions the 2D case is essentially the same, except for the extra factor of $r$ that you get from the polar coordinate transformation. But you can modify your function to cancel out this factor, so that the integral in polar coordinates looks just like the 1D case from before.